What is in-sample vs out-of-sample in a multiple linear regression?
I was just thinking about what would be considered interpolation vs extrapolation for multiple linear regression, and realised I'm not sure exactly how it would be defined, nor could I find an answer online.
Specifically, say you have a random collection of $d$-dimensional points $x_j$ for $1 \leq j \leq n$, and I obtain a multiple regression estimate $\beta$. Then if I take some other point $a$ and predict with $\hat{y}=\beta^Ta$, what conditions on $a$ would make this in-sample vs out-of-sample?
I was thinking you could consider the hyper-rectangle that is formed by the points $x_j$, but this still feels like you can have points that are not within the realm of your training data. Alternatively I was thinking perhaps it would be defined by the minimum convex body that includes all the $x_j$?

Both your question and proposed convex hull approach are reasonable, but I don't think you will find a strong consensus on this. There is even some disagreement about what constitutes interpolation vs. extrapolation when considering a single dimension (see the comments under the first couple of answers):
Extrapolation v. Interpolation
